# GridView Retain the TextColor on Click

Tags: android, gridview, textview

Hello There I am new to Android Development!
I am learning it to my own, I just have a grid view with multiple text views inside it. I want to change the text color of the text view on which I click!
The text view should change its color to which i click on.

I am doing it like:
This is my GridView Item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_tv_categories"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/text_pressed"
        android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My Selector xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

</selector>
```

The adapter is:

```
private static final class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        final ArrayList<CategoryModel> mItems;
        final int mCount;
        final Context ctx;
        TextView text = null;
        View view;
        /**
         * Default constructor
         *
         * @param items to fill data to
         */
        private GridAdapter(final ArrayList<CategoryModel> items, Context ctx) {

            mCount = items.size();
            //mItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            mItems = items;
            this.ctx=ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCount;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(final int position) {
            return mItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(final int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

           view = convertView;


            if (view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

                text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
            }

            final CategoryModel myItem = mItems.get(position);

            if (text != null)
                text.setText(myItem.name);
            //text.setText(mItems.get(position));


            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //text.setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_77));
                    categories = myItem.id;
                    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "" + myItem.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

It does change the text color but only when I click it I mean I want to retain the blue color of the text view text on which i click on,

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your adapter code

Comment: updated my question please check the adapter code

Comment: Not clear on what you are looking for? Can you share screenshots of what the expected output is, and what the current output is?

Comment: I just want to change the color of the text view item in the grid view on click even!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_tv_categories"
```

and in your adapter, do like

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //text.setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_77));
                text.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.blue_light));
                categories = myItem.id;
                //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "" + myItem.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

1. Add one field in your CategoryModel called 'clicked'
2. set this field true when its clicked
3. call notifydatasetchanged() method
4. in your adapter getview() method

final CategoryModel myItem = mItems.get(position);

```
if(myItem.clicked){
      yourTextView.settextcolor("your color");
}else{
      yourTextView.settextcolor("default color");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter code

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

       view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);


        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
        }

        final CategoryModel myItem = mItems.get(position);

        if (text != null)
            text.setText(myItem.name);
        //text.setText(mItems.get(position));


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //change the color
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
                categories = myItem.id;
                //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "" + myItem.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: its not working because when load the new data will also change the color. I have try it..